# Construct an example of a $4×4$ matrix, with one of its eigenvalues equal to $−1$, that is not diagonal or diagonalizable, but is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Construct an example of a $4×4$ matrix, with one of its eigenvalues equal to $−1$, that is not diagonal or diagonalizable, but is invertible.

I am not completely sure how to start with this exercise. I know how to find a matrix that is not diagonal but not sure how to make it invertible .

Comment: Try a Jordan matrix.

Comment: (-1,1,0,0)(0,-1,1,0)(0,0,-1,1)(0,0,0,-1) like this in matrix form

Comment: You answer is poorly formatted. Looks like telephone number!

Answer (score 2):

We can use a [*Jordan Form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), try

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the LOWER (initially said wrongly as upper) triangular matrix where all the entries  are 1, except the very last entry at $a_{nn}$ which should be $-1$.  This should do.

Comment: This is a nice answer too (+1).

Comment: How do you show this is not diagonalizable?

Comment: The vector $e_n$ is an eigenvector of eigen value $-1$. The other eigen values are $+1$. Trying to find the solutions of $(A-I)v=0$ would clinch it.